# How to reference AWS local prefix list in terraform route table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

If I have the below route table, how can create a route which uses the AWS `local` prefix list?

```
resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
  }

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    destination_prefix_list_id = "local"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "public"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: "local prefix list" - what is that? Do you have any example?

Comment: I added an image, but basically it is the default target. I'm not sure if I need to add it or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `local` route is always present by **default**. You don't have to do anything to add it, nor you can remove it.

Comment: As a word of explanation, `Local` is there to allow your deployed resources to reach each-other within the subnet (not taking any firewalls rules into account).